# Search across multiple views

Tags: 7, views, search

I have a page with two view blocks in it, each pulling from different content types. Is there a way to allow the user to *search both views at the same time*? I want to be able to enter a search term and have both views be filtered by this term.

---

**Edit**: Going off of johnbburg's answer, I found a [solution using Panels](https://www.drupal.org/node/1547774), but would really like to avoid adding Panels to the site. Perhaps I could use javascript to insert the search term into the other field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is implementing some custom code that adds an input field to the page, and takes that input and feeds in into the multiple block filters on the page, just using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "Filter identifier" for each exposed filter to use the same name. This is available under the "MORE" options in the filter's settings.

[image]

These will be used as GET parameters in the request and picked up by both views. This however also means that you can't use ajax with either views as they need to detect the parameter during a page request.

Comment: Don't you have to use ajax to have exposed filters in view blocks? How do you display the exposed filter then?